# Equation of the hyperplane for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-algebra

I'm doing a ML MOOC through Edx(archived) and am trying to figure out what theta is for hyperplanes.

So the equation is

[image]

When Theta = [-1, 1.5] and Theta_0 = [3], we have:

[image]

How do I interpret theta? I thought it was [change in x, change in y], but the line in the image looks like it has slope positive (2/3). Also, I thought Theta_0 represented the the y-intercept, but the intercept seems to be at -2.  What is the equation representing if not the hyperplane?

The scale on both axis is one.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever i get from your question 
 `Theta_1 = [-1, 1.5]` and `Theta_0 = [3]` which simply means you have two features and you are interpreting this as one feature equation.

Main equation becomes :

```
Theta_0 + Theta_1*X1 + Theta_2*X2
```